# Is there any option in Illustrator to open raster layer's PSD in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

As we know, in Photoshop, we have option to paste vectors from Illustrator to Photoshop and later we can double click it and edit-save in Illustrator to modify it.

Sometimes for print, I have to work on both Photoshop and Illustrator. The main file I create is in Illustrator. Only the raster stuff is done in Photoshop, and then I import them in Illustrator.

But when you have to fix/change the raster images, you have to again go to Photoshop, make changes, export it and open again in Illustrator. It looks a little tedious.

**So is there any option so we can somehow achieve the same *experience* in Illustrator?**

For example: Make an image in Photoshop, export/copy (format I'm not sure for the solution of this question. Currently I use JPG or PNG) it and open/paste in Illustrator print document. Later, when you want to edit it just *double click* and edit-save (the main PSD) in Photoshop, to reflect in Illustrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *File > Place ...* and place the original PSD file. No need to save a JPG or PNG every time.

The *Window > Links* panel will show you a list of all placed images.

When you select one of the placed images (either directly or from the list), you can click the tiny *Edit Original* pencil button in the corner to edit the original.

If a placed image is changed in Photoshop *without* clicking the *Edit Original* button, a yellow warning is shown besides the filename, and you can select the image and click the *Update Link* button to reflect the change.

Pressing the *Relink* button will enable you to change the placed image to another image.

This way of working with placed original images instead of pasted embedded images is in my opinion the best and most versatile way to work. (Also in InDesign).

Comment: Thank you! That was what I needed. But now I have one more doubt related to it. For this, we have to use PSD, instead of PNG or JPG. Wouldn't it make Illustrator slow compared to exported images?

Comment: No, I was not being precise. You can place any kind of image. It was because you talked about having an original layered psd (or tif) and then saving jpg/png from that to place in Illustrator. That's one unnecessary step. Much easier to just place the layered file.

Comment: But you're right - it can probably be a little slower. I think Illustrator will use the flattened preview of the psd. Don't think it has to render all layers and effects all the time.

Comment: I would seldom place png because I mainly make things for print where png isn't recommended to use.

Comment: You also use this feature?

Comment: To place images rather than embed them? Yes always. (I mainly work in InDesign though but it's the same idea)

Comment: Placed image would be linked and not embedded right?

Comment: Yes, linked. To keep the design file and the images separate.

Comment: placed PSD* I meant.